# React not re-rendering the components after the first try

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Kinda a React noobie. So, please don't judge me.

The Header is rendering perfectly but I just get Loading... for the SearchBar!!

I am not even able to see the components because of which I'm not even able to handle form submissions etc.

The GET requests made using axios are working perfectly without the React stuff. (like when I try to make a GET request from Postman, the endpoints work fine.)

Here are my components:

1. App.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'babel-polyfill';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import SearchBar from './../components/layout/SearchBar';

import Header from './layout/Header';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allGenes: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios
      .get('/api/find_all_genes')
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          allGenes: result.data.genes
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
        <Header />
        <SearchBar genes={this.state.allGenes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

2. SearchBar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Autocomplete from 'react-autocomplete';
import axios from 'axios';
import Variants from './Variants';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allVariants: []
    };
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    axios
      .get(`/api/find_all_variants/?q=${this.state.value}`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          variants: res.data.variants
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.getData();
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.allGenes && this.props.allGenes.length > 0) {
      const allGenes = this.props.allGenes;
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>Enter gene name</h3>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Autocomplete
              value={this.state.value}
              items={allGenes}
              getItemValue={item => item}
              inputProps={{ id: 'states-autocomplete' }}
              wrapperStyle={{ position: 'relative', display: 'inline-block' }}
              renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) => (
                <div
                  style={{ background: isHighlighted ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }}
                >
                  {item.label}
                </div>
              )}
              onChange={(event, value) => this.setState({ value })}
              onSelect={value => this.setState({ value })}
            />

            <input type="submit" value="submit" className="btn" />
          </form>
          <Variants variants={this.state.variants} />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <h1 style={{ color: 'black' }}>Loading...</h1>;
    }
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

3. Variants.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
// import 'react-table/react-table.css';

class Variants extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: 'Gene',
        accessor: 'gene'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Nucleotide Change',
        accessor: 'nucleotide_change'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Protein Change',
        accessor: 'protein_change'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Other Mappings',
        accessor: 'other_mappings'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Alias',
        accessor: 'alias'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Transcripts',
        accessor: 'transcripts'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Region',
        accessor: 'region'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Reported Classification',
        accessor: 'reported_classification'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Inferred Classification',
        accessor: 'inferred_classification'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Source',
        accessor: 'source'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Last Evaluated',
        accessor: 'last_evaluated'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Last Updated',
        accessor: 'last_updated'
      },
      {
        Header: 'More Information',
        accessor: 'url',
        Cell: e => (
          <a target="_blank" href={e.value}>
            {' '}
            {e.value}{' '}
          </a>
        )
      },
      {
        Header: 'Submitter Comment',
        accessor: 'submitter_comment'
      }
    ];
    if (this.props.variants.length > 0) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>
            {' '}
            There are {this.props.variants.length} variants of this{' '}
            {this.props.value}!
          </h2>
          <div className="table">
            <ReactTable
              data={this.props.variants}
              columns={columns}
              defaultPageSize={3}
              pageSizeOptions={[3, 5, 10, 50, 100]}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
}

export default Variants;
```

4. Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
          aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
            Gene Variants
          </a>
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0" />
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use your search bar component you use it like this `<SearchBar genes={this.state.allGenes} />`. However in the search bar you try to refer to allGenes using `this.props.allGenes`

Props is the properties assigned to a component when that component is used, and adopts the name given when you call that component. Therefore you are passing the SearchBar component a "genes" prop instead of an "allGenes" prop.

You can either change where you use the SearchBar component and pass allGenes prop like this: `<SearchBar allGenes={this.state.allGenes} />`
Or you can refer to the prop you actually gave the search bar (inside the search bar refer to `this.props.genes`)

Comment: That fixed my initial problem. Do you see any problem with Autocomplete? It is not getting rendered at all.

Comment: Glad it sorted that issue. I don't have any experience with this autocomplete library but I would hazard a guess that the data and what you are trying to render don't match up. Does each gene object have a label assigned?

Answer (score 2):

Your "if" condition is not being met because you're not passing the right property value.

```
<SearchBar genes={this.state.allGenes} />
```

it should be **allGenes**

Answer (score 2):

`<SearchBar genes={this.state.allGenes} />`

In this line, your prop name is `gene` but while accessing it in SearchBar you're using `this.props.allGenes`.